# call java class from SAS. ERROR: Could not find class

Tags: java, sas, sas-macro

```
    data Numbers;
        do i=1 to 10;
            output;
        end;
    run;

    data PrimeNumbers;
        set Numbers;
        if _N_=1 then declare javaobj j("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\checkPrimeNumber");
        isPrimeNumber=j.callIntMethod("checkPrimeNumber",i);
        if isPrimeNumber=1 then output;
    run;


    /*-SET CLASSPATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"*/


    /*--------------------------Sample java code----------------------------
    public class checkPrimeNumber 
    {
        public checkPrimeNumber() 
        {
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            checkPrimeNumber CPN=new checkPrimeNumber();
            System.out.println ("Result:"+CPN.checkPrimeNumber(23));
        }
        public int checkPrimeNumber(int num) 
        {
            for (int i=2; i<=(num/2); i++) 
                if ((num%i) == 0)
                 return 0;
            return 1;
        }   
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Log:------->

```
        ERROR: Could not find class C:\checkPrimeNumber at line 45 column 44.  Please ensure that the
               CLASSPATH is correct.
        ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\checkPrimeNumber
             at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I have set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin` and compiled & executed the program from command prompt. Code works fine from command prompt. But SAS code throws an Error, so I added  `-set CLASSPATH`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin`statement in`sasv9.cfg`located at`SASFoundation\9.3\nls\en`. I still get the same error( same as mentioned above). What could be wrong? Where should I add classpath variable in SAS files/folders so that SAS identify java classpath?

Comment: I don't know what SAS is but try setting the classpath to where your `checkPrimeNumber.class` is and use `j("checkPrimeNumber")`

Comment: @RC. I have put java file in jdk bin directory, & changed the path of class file in SAS code (see above). I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In your sasv9.cfg file you should look for -JREOPTIONS option. Inside this option add you path to the parameter -Dsas.app.class.path

When declaring java object in data step you can pass only the class name - not the all path. So the declaration should looks like:

```
declare javaobj j("checkPrimeNumber")
```

And the last one. The return value from java method is passed to the last argument in data step function. Calling java method should go like this:

```
j.callIntMethod("checkPrimeNumbers",i,isPrimeNumber);
```

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try running PROC JAVAINFO to determine if your classpath is set correctly. Classpath can be set in a number of ways in different places. It is perfectly possible that it gets overwritten later in load up process.

Also, are you running the code on what sort of server? Is it remote or local?

To set classpath at runtime in datastep, following this advice: http://support.sas.com/kb/38/518.html

Vasilij

Comment: its local...When I execute proc javainfo, I get, java.class.path = C:\PROGRA~1\SASHome\SASVER~1\eclipse\plugins\SASLAU~1.JAR What should I do?

Comment: I must say I do not know why that classpath doesn't feed through in your case. It could be getting changed somewhere else. Anyway, try this advice on setting classpath in the datastep: http://support.sas.com/kb/38/518.html